# How to parse a file and exclude lines that share the same values?

Tags: shell, parsing, logging, strace

I am trying to parse a output file that is generated by a script thatIi made, the script is for [strace](/questions/tagged/strace).

Bellow is the an example of a parsed log:

```
17:21:07 mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6ffb000 <0.000326>
17:21:07 mmap2(NULL, 8859, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6ff8000 <0.000337>
17:21:07 mmap2(NULL, 430216, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f6c000 <0.000479>
17:21:07 mmap2(0xb6fd4000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x68000) = 0xb6fd4000 <0.000571>
17:21:07 mmap2(NULL, 1258856, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6e38000 <0.000517>
17:21:07 mmap2(0xb6f66000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x126000) = 0xb6f66000 <0.001654>
17:21:07 mmap2(0xb6f69000, 9576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f69000 <0.002229>
17:21:07 mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6ff7000 <0.000071>
17:21:07 munmap(0xb6ff8000, 8859)       = 0 <0.000568>
17:21:07 mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6ffa000 <0.000082>
```

This is the line i use for parsing :

```
cat ${traced}_brut.txt | grep "map" > ${traced}_parced.txt
```

Now, what i want to do is remove the lines that have the same hex value, so i can better spot memory leaks.

For example in this case, the bellow lines should disappear from the final log file because they share the same hex value:

```
17:21:07 mmap2(NULL, 8859, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6ff8000 <0.000337>
17:21:07 munmap(0xb6ff8000, 8859)
```

Answer (score 0):

**With basic shell commands (I'm on AIX 6. [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh))**

First, find your duplicates, e.g. with this `sed` / `sort` / `uniq`, registered to a new file (say input is in a.txt):

```
 sed -e 's/\(.*\)\(0x........\)\(.*\)/\2/' a.txt |sort  | uniq -c
```

So with your input in "a.txt":

```
   1 0xb6e38000
   1 0xb6f66000
   1 0xb6f69000
   1 0xb6f6c000
   1 0xb6fd4000
   1 0xb6ff7000
   2 0xb6ff8000
   1 0xb6ffa000
   1 0xb6ffb000
```

Then we can add a `grep  -v "   1 0x"| cut -c 6- | tr -d '[:blank:]' > exclude.lst` in order to have the duplicates only in `exclude.lst` (beware if you have more than 9 duplicates in the input, it will shift, so you should elaborate a little more); (*edit*: added `tr -d '[:blank:]'` to remove possible blank spaces)

Then re-use the file to `grep -v` your input;

```
grep -vf exclude.lst a.txt
```

**edit1**

To sum it up, you would do it with these 3 lines:

```
cat ${traced}_brut.txt | grep "map" > ${traced}_parced.txt 
sed -e 's/\(.*\)\(0x........\)\(.*\)/\2/' ${traced}_parced.txt |sort | uniq -c | grep -v " 1 0x"| cut -c 6- | tr -d '[:blank:]' > exclude.lst 
#grep -vf exclude.lst ${traced}_parced.txt > ${traced}_final.txt
# above worked for me, but you may need to specify -F
grep -F -vf exclude.lst ${traced}_parced.txt > ${traced}_final.txt
```

**edit2**
I did the search for you; maybe we could try this `-F` from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83260/reading-grep-patterns-from-a-file ? Edited above summary.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Hello, i tried the code but it doesn't seem to work and also if there are more then 9 duplicates what the ?

Comment: So what i did was : 

`cat ${traced}_brut.txt | grep "map" > ${traced}_parced.txt`

`sed -e 's/\(.*\)\(0x........\)\(.*\)/\2/' ${traced}_parced.txt |sort  | uniq -c | 
grep  -v "   1 0x"| cut -c 6- > exclude.lst`

`grep -vf exclude.lst ${traced}_parced.txt > ${traced}_final.txt`

Comment: The exclusion list works fine but when i do the last grep command it does nothing, i tried egrep and fgrep , but the txt file that is supposed to give the final parsed text nothing happens it stays the same and doesn't exclude the lines that are in the exclusion list.

Comment: The content in ${traced}_final.txt is the same as in ${traced}_parsed.txt .
As for the  `| tr -d '[:blank:]'` i didnt test it but where would you put it in the code.

Comment: The result is the same, it doesn't parse the txt. it just copies it to the other file.

Comment: Could you give me the exact content of `exclude.lst`? what does your `grep` man page says about options `v` and `f`? You have most of it, you should try to find out by yourself.

Comment: I checked and it has the options v and f, also the content of the exclude.lst works as intended.

Comment: let's try with `-F`, what do you think?

Comment: I was thinking about something else, lets reverse the process and print in the exclude file the ones that are unique and the grep them from the parsed file.

Comment: This sounds great for **another** more specific question. Good luck. In the meantime, if you think my answer was mildly useful, don't hesitated to [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it.

Comment: @biotic, if you accept my answer, then you'll get +2 rep. I think "odd number" is what you're looking for, not "prime number" in your other question.